# How can I include all js files like we add all css files in one main.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We can use all css files as one file for example main.css:

```
@import url(bootstrap.css);
@import url(bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(bootstrap-theme.css);
@import url(bootstrap-theme.min.css);
@import url(style.css);
@import url(w3.css);
```

How can we include and use all js files as one main.js and use all javascript files for example

main.js

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:7070/js/aa.js">
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:7070/js/bb.js">
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:7070/js/cc.js">
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:7070/js/dd.js">
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:7070/js/ee.js">
```

Comment: Research 'bundling' and 'minification' of JS files. Exactly how you do it depends on when and how you want it done.

Comment: You might also take a look on http://requirejs.org/ library that could help you with managing javascript files.

Answer (score 2):

You can't natively include JS files like the import statement in CSS (though it's important to note that the CSS import still downloads multiple files, it's just a convenience for organizing the rules.  )

Have a look at tools like Webpack, require.js, Grunt, and Gulp.  All of which do concatenation and minification for you as build steps.

Comment: can you please quote any example from any tool that you mentioned in your answer that could tell how can I achieve my goal

Comment: most of the tools are combining files data as copy paste as one whereas I am looking for exact solution that I mentioned above

Comment: @Ghayel there isn't one, and in fact the solution you described doesn't do what you say it does.  What the import statement in CSS does is downloads the referenced file and then, effectively, copies and pastes the imported file in the spot of the file that the import statement is at.  It's actually *less* efficient than the solutions I proposed, as it fires off a network request for each file in addition to the 'main.css' one.

Comment: I am not seeing any solution except recommending some softwares. if these softwares can do then I believe there must be some way to achieve my goal via writing a code in simple notepad

Comment: Then go write some code in simple notepad and post it here if it doesn't work.